# jQuery ui sortable: How to disallow the nesting of groups while allowing all the items to be inter-sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following nested sortable code using jQuery:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="listContainer">
  <ul>
    <li class="listItem">Item 1</li>
    <li class="listItem groupItem">
      <ul>
        <div class="groupTitle">Group A</div>
        <li class="listItem">Item 2</li>
        <li class="listItem">Item 3</li>
        <li class="listItem">Item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">Item 5</li>
    <li class="listItem">Item 6</li>
    <li class="listItem groupItem">
      <ul>
        <div class="groupTitle">Group B</div>
        <li class="listItem">Item 7</li>
        <li class="listItem">Item 8</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">Item 9</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$( "#listContainer ul" ).sortable({
  connectWith: "#listContainer ul",
  placeholder: "itemPlaceholder",
  cursor: 'move'
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmxes/o3fosdzn/1/)

**There are 2 problems I am facing currently:**

**- If I drag the group title it moves only the title line, but I want to move the complete group.**

**- I don't want to allow nesting of groups. Currently you can move and nest the group inside another group, but only the items should be moved.**

Comment: You should make use of `handles` http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your DEMO and created a [**NEW DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/o3fosdzn/3/).

**In this DEMO:**

> - All the items are sortable from outer list to the group list and vice versa and the items can also be sorted among the the groups.
> - The groups cannot be nested. An alert will popup if nesting of group is attempted

**Please note that to achieve this, you will need to make structure changes of the list items and as you would have observed in the demo.**

Here is the code from the demo:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="listContainer">
<ul class="srtable">
  <li class="listItem">Item 1</li>
  <li class="listItem groupItem">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="groupTitle">Group A</div>
      <div class="listItem">Item 2</div>
      <div class="listItem">Item 3</div>
      <div class="listItem">Item 4</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="listItem">Item 5</li>
  <li class="listItem">Item 6</li>
  <li class="listItem groupItem">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="groupTitle">Group B</div>
      <div class="listItem">Item 7</div>
      <div class="listItem">Item 8</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="listItem">Item 9</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$( "#listContainer ul" ).sortable(
{
    connectWith: ".group",
  placeholder: "itemPlaceholder",
  cursor: 'move'
  }
);

$('.group').sortable({
    items: "> div.listItem",
  connectWith: ".srtable, .group",
  receive: function( event, ui ) {
    //alert('receive');
    //console.log(ui);
    //console.log(ui.item)
    //console.log($(ui.item).attr('class'))
    if ($(ui.item).hasClass('groupItem')) {
      $(ui.sender).sortable("cancel");
      alert('Sorry! Groups cannot be nested');
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe my wording was not the best. Simple items should be moved to any place. I only want to avoid nested groups.

Comment: @Vmxes I have now modified my answer, please have a look. I think I have achieved what you wanted. Let me know if still there are any issues

Comment: Glad to help you! :)